# devtools::install_github fails with CA cert error

Tags: r, ssl-certificate, rcurl, devtools

When I try to call install_github, I get the following error (not just for this package, but for all github packages):

```
> install_github('ramnathv/slidify')
Downloading github repo ramnathv/slidify@master
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

But if I use RCurl directly to access github with ssl, I don't get any problem:

```
>  x <- getBinaryURL(
          url='https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/archive/master.zip',
          followlocation=1L
          )
```

works with no errors, so RCurl can verify the SSL certificate properly and download the archive file.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C             
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.utf8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.utf8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.utf8       LC_NAME=C                
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C           
 [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RCurl_1.95-4.7 bitops_1.0-6   devtools_1.8.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.0.0      R6_2.1.0        magrittr_1.5    rversions_1.0.2
 [5] tools_3.2.1     curl_0.9.1      Rcpp_0.12.0     memoise_0.2.1  
 [9] xml2_0.1.1      stringi_0.5-5   git2r_0.10.1    stringr_1.0.0  
 [13] digest_0.6.8
```

And

```
> curlVersion()

$age
[1] 3

$version
[1] "7.38.0"

$vesion_num
[1] 468480

$host
[1] "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

$features
   ipv6         ssl        libz        ntlm   asynchdns      spnego 
      1           4           8          16         128         256 
   largefile         idn tlsauth_srp     ntlm_wb 
    512        1024       16384       32768 

$ssl_version
[1] "OpenSSL/1.0.1k"

$ssl_version_num
[1] 0

$libz_version
[1] "1.2.8"

$protocols
[1] "dict"   "file"   "ftp"    "ftps"   "gopher" "http"   "https"  "imap"  
[9] "imaps"  "ldap"   "ldaps"  "pop3"   "pop3s"  "rtmp"   "rtsp"   "scp"   
[17] "sftp"   "smtp"   "smtps"  "telnet" "tftp"  

$ares
[1] ""

$ares_num
[1] 0

$libidn
[1] "1.29"
```

If I use `httr::set_config( httr::config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )` then I can successfully run `install_github` but I would prefer to actually check ssl certificates.

Can anyone offer a solution?

Answer (score 19):

Finally figured this out.

I had two different ssl libraries installed and for some reason, the RCurl package built against libcurl4-openssl-dev and the curl package built against libcurl4-nss-dev, but I had only installed CA keys for openssl, not for nss.

I solved my problem with `remove.packages('curl')` in R and then quitting R and from the shell `apt-get remove libcurl4-nss-dev` starting R and `install.packages('curl')`

My mistake, which led to my question, was to test the SSL CA handling using `RCurl` instead of `httr` or `curl`, which would have led me quickly to the fact that my `curl` package was linked to the wrong SSL library.

Comment: Exactly my case.. Saved my life on Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If `httr` lib is missing the same error appears

try:

> install.packages("httr")

Answer (score 0):

I removed `httr` (deleting the whole httr folder directly from my R win-library) and reinstalled it. Then, installation from github worked smoothly

Answer (score 0):

When I use library swirl I met the same problem tooooo

After several try and find, I found that is because I haven't install openssl in R.

So:

```
install.packages("openssl")
```

then, everything ok!

Oh! I am using Windows 10, not Linux

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error with swirl while submitting assignments for Coursera.
Uninstall and reinstall swirl itself, curl and htrr (which was also missing) did not address the issue. The only thing that actually worked was:

install.packages("openssl")

Also using Windows 10 and R 3.3.3.

Comment: Plase, see this before answering. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, the current version of R has the package `curl` installed: `install.packages('curl')`