# package ‘taskscheduleR’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)

Tags: r, rstudio, package

I get the error of the above title. I carefully looked at the spelling of the package ‘taskscheduleR' and it seems correct. I actually don't see it in the packages list:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html

I learned about this taskscheduleR package on this link:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/taskscheduler-r-package-to-schedule-r-scripts-with-the-windows-task-manager/

Do you know how I can get this package ? If not existing anymore can I find out why ? I would like to automate some scripts on a daily basis.
Thanks!

Max

Comment: Follow this guide: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/githubinstall/vignettes/githubinstall.html

Comment: In the link provided it tells you where the package is available...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's available on the CRAN but it's available on github :  https://github.com/bnosac/taskscheduleR

Comment: Yes I had found it but when I run this devtools::install_github("bnosac/taskscheduleR")                                  Iget the following error: "Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates" What difference does it make  the fact that it is not coming from the CRAN repository?

Comment: Regarding this error, I saw this issue on another package : https://github.com/jimhester/gmailr/issues/44 . The owner of package conclusion is  "you need to update the curl package. However the error you are getting looks to me like your CA certificates are either not being found appropriately or are outdated in your OS."

Comment: I also found this SO answer for your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643036/devtoolsinstall-github-fails-with-ca-cert-error