# using Rselenium trougth a Proxy: not accepting certificat

Tags: r, rselenium

I would like to use Rselenium behind a Proxy, but it seems that the certicat ins't accepted

```
Sys.setenv(https_proxy="https://proxyurl:1080")
Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http://proxyurl:1080")
Sys.setenv(http_proxy_user="user:mdp")
Sys.setenv(https_proxy_user="user:mdp")

library(RSelenium)

driver<- rsDriver()
```

> checking Selenium Server versions: 
>   BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD 
>   Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
>   Problem with the SSL CA cert (path?
>   access rights?)

any idea how I can correct this ?

Regards

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643036/devtoolsinstall-github-fails-with-ca-cert-error